# How to get a collection in MongoDB sorted by days per month

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to create an aggregation where we get an array of days in a month and fill it with relevant data?

For example, we have expenses. I want to get all the expenses in November.

```
{
  title: "Apple",
  value:15,
  createdAt: 2023-10-09T20:00:34.575+00:00
},
{
  title: "Meet",
  value:30,
  createdAt: 2023-10-11T20:00:34.575+00:00
},
{
  title: "Egg",
  value:10,
  createdAt: 2023-10-16T20:00:34.575+00:00
},
```

As a result, I want to get something like this:

```
[
 {day: '01', expenses: ['all expenses on the current day']},
 {day: '02', expenses: ['empty if without expenses on this day]},
 ...
 {day: '31', expenses: [
  { title: 'Egg', value: 10, createdAt: '2023-10-31T20:00:34.575+00:00' }
  ]},
]
```

Comment: Please edit to include a [mcve]. Tl;dr you have to show your work (code, expected vs actual output, etc).

Comment: Also - your example result doesn't seem to match your sample data, with `'Egg'` having a different date (and not in November).

Comment: Did you try grouping by $dayOfMonth?